# Symfony HWIOAuthBundle, how to configure cURL?

Tags: symfony, curl, ssl, certificate, hwioauthbundle

On the development machine we have the default certificates that comes with apache, when we trying to authenticate with facebook, [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) fires an exception:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

It's clear that in plain PHP we need to set an option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false`, and pass to `curl_setopt_array(...)`.

How can we define these options for Symfony or for [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add following options under "hwi_oauth" and you should be fine.

```
hwi_oauth:
    http_client:
        verify_peer: false
```