# Symfony DomCrawler status code not working?

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler

hii this is my php code fore get status on url.

```
 $client = new Client();
        $url_to_traverse = 'http://wordcomat.com';
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url_to_traverse);
        $status_code = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();
```

but i try to found status code of facebook it's not return any thing.

```
 $client = new Client();
        $url_to_traverse = 'http://www.facebook.com';

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url_to_traverse);
        $status_code = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();
```

twitter not working.

```
 $client = new Client();
        $url_to_traverse = 'http://www.twitter.com';

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url_to_traverse);
        $status_code = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();
```

facebook or twitter or linkedin or google is not return any thing but not return any error or warning how can i got status of that links.

thank you.

Answer (score 5):

thy are using  **https** protocol

try the following

```
    $client = new Client();
    $url_to_traverse = 'https://www.facebook.com';

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url_to_traverse);
    $status_code = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();
```

Comment: i got exception cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522963/symfony-hwioauthbundle-how-to-configure-curl